# Possible bug with forms and arrays? Multiple forms on one view and Array fields in Models ---: Django and Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-forms, django-views, django-1.8

I get a strange error and I can't find the solution. The view is used to create data entries for a user but with an option to go back and edit hence the singular view to deal with an update...

The code works with only one form being pulled into the view but not with several, then it gives a nonsensical error.

This is all in one app with its own set of urls.py

I have entered in the data raw for now in the form field rendered so eg interests : [1,2,3,4,5] in those fields
This worked as its should with no errors or abnormalities (data was updated in field)  but when i added skills through incremental development it shows this error:

missing "]" in array dimensions
    LINE 1: ...akeProfile_skills" SET "user_id" = 11, "skills" =  '[0,1,2,3,..

I am using :
postgres1.9
Python3.4
Django 1.8.7

Code:

view.py

```
@login_required
def step2(request):

    title =" Step 2 of 4 "
    # if request.method.upper() == 'POST':
    #     print('hello free stackoverflow points')

    #user_answer = UserAnswer.objects.get(user=request.user, question =instance)
    #profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    form2p0 = step2p0Form()
    form2p1 = step2p1Form()
    form2p2 = step2p2Form()


    context ={
        "title":title,
        "form2p0":form2p0,
        "form2p1":form2p1,
        "form2p2":form2p2,

    }
    #skills, created = Skills.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method.upper() == 'POST':

        interests, created = Interests.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        skills, created = Skills.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        languages, created = Languages.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

        form2p0 = step2p0Form(request.POST or None, instance= interests)
        form2p1 = step2p1Form(request.POST or None, instance= skills)
        form2p2 = step2p2Form(request.POST or None, instance= languages)

        context ={
            "title":title,
            "form2p0":form2p0,
            "form2p1":form2p1,
            "form2p2":form2p2,

        }

        if  form2p0.is_valid() and form2p1.is_valid() and form2p2.is_valid():

            instance2p0 =form2p0.save(commit=False)
            instance2p1 =form2p1.save(commit=False)
            instance2p2 =form2p2.save(commit=False)

            interests = form2p0.cleaned_data.get('interests')
            instance2p0.user = request.user
            instance2p0.interest = interests

            skills= form2p1.cleaned_data.get('skills')
            instance2p1.user = request.user
            instance2p1.skills = skills

            languages =  form2p2.cleaned_data.get('languages')
            instance2p2.languages = languages

            instance2p0.save()
            instance2p1.save()
            instance2p2.save()


            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('makeProfile:step3'))

    return render(request, "profile/step2.html", context)
```

form.py

```
class step2p0Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model =Interests
       fields = ['interests']

    interests = forms.CharField(required = True)

class step2p1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model =Skills
        fields = ['skills']

    skills = forms.CharField(required = True)

class step2p2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Languages
        fields =['languages']

    languages = forms.CharField()
```

model.py

```
class Skills(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True)
#skills = models.CharField(max_length = 128, null=True, blank=True)
skills =  ArrayField(models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True, default = -1 ))


class Interests(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True)
#interests = models.CharField(max_length = 128, null=True, blank=True)
interests =  ArrayField(models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True, default = -1))




class Languages(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True)

languages =  ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,default="None"))



#*******************SIGNALS***********************


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

if not created:
   print("hello#########")
   return

profile = Profile(user=instance)
interests = Interests(user=instance)
skills= Skills(user=instance)
languages = Languages(user=instance)

interests.interests = [0]
skills.skills = [0]
languages.languages = ["None"]

skills.save()
interests.save()
languages.save()
profile.save()



DataError at /makeProfile/step2/
missing "]" in array dimensions
LINE 1: ...akeProfile_skills" SET "user_id" = 11, "skills" =  '[0,1,2,3,...
                                                         ^
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8888/makeProfile/step2/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: DataError
Exception Value:    
missing "]" in array dimensions
LINE 1: ...akeProfile_skills" SET "user_id" = 11, "skills" =  '[0,1,2,3,...
                                                         ^
Exception Location: /home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-p   ackages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 64
Python Executable:  /home/g4/django/pureRu/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/home/g4/django/pureRu/src',
'/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4',
'/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python3.4',
'/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 27 Nov 2015 18:42:54 +0000
```

TrackBack:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/makeProfile/step2/

Django Version: 1.8.7
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'crispy_forms',
'registration',
'newsletter',
'questions',
'makeProfile')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')
```

Traceback:

```
    File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request,   *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
     File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/src/makeProfile/views.py" in step2
      111.             instance2p1.save()
    File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
      734.                        force_update=force_update,   update_fields=update_fields)
     File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
      762.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert,  force_update, using, update_fields)
    File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site- packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
      827.                                       forced_update)
      File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_update
      877.         return filtered._update(values) > 0
      File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site- packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _update
      580.         return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site- packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
      1062.         cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler,   self).execute_sql(result_type)
      File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
       79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql,   params)
      File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
       64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
       File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site- packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
      98.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
      File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
      685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/home/g4/django/pureRu/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

     Exception Type: DataError at /makeProfile/step2/
     Exception Value: missing "]" in array dimensions
     LINE 1: ...akeProfile_skills" SET "user_id" = 11, "skills" =   '[0,1,2,3,..
.^
```

I am hoping its not a typo if you read all of that but I have had two eyes on this code and have checked it a million times.... So at this stage I am just hoping someone out there can help.

Thank you

Comment: What is ArrayField? Where is it coming from? What is the code?

Comment: The array field in models which maps to the type array in the Postgres db

Comment: `postgres1.9`? Interesting. :)

Answer (score 0):

SO.......... Not sure if this is the fix but its working, all I changed was the order inside of things: Grouped it like that then magic... could have been a typo ain the above code but it works now hence i'm going with the order of form2p0.save(commit = False) and  instance2p0.save()

Hence:

```
    instance2p0 = form2p0.save(commit = False)
    interestsEdit = form2p1.cleaned_data.get('interests')
    instance2p0.Interests = interestsEdit
    instance2p0.save()


    instance2p0 = form2p0.save(commit = False)
    skillsEdit = form2p1.cleaned_data.get('skills')
    instance2p0.Skills = skillsEdit
    instance2p0.save()
```